# lynx unix command not working with more than one parameter in URL

Tags: php, linux

I am trying to run URL using lynx through PHP, below is my code as I'm using.

```
shell_exec(lynx 'www.example.com&post=123&auth=45);
```

something like that.

Now issue I noticed is that while I'm running command manually at terminal not using PHP it has an issue with two parameter, however it's working quite smooth with one parameter or without any.

After running two parameter it's showing something like
[1] or [2] and then DONE. I don't know exactly what went wrong.

Comment: why would you use lynx like this ? What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: "something like that" — You've got PHP **and** shell syntax errors there. Don't show us something like your code, show us real code that really demonstrates your problem.

Comment: I also tried with  -accept_all_cookies parameters still it has same issue

Comment: And don't shell out to lynx to make an HTTP request. PHP has a perfectly serviceable set of bindings to the [cURL](http://php.net/curl/) library.

Answer (score 2):

```
shell_exec('lynx "http://www.example.com?post=123&auth=45"');
```

You have typos there, first you need to pass the argument of shell_exec as string, next if you need to use ampersand (&) in the url, you need to enclose the url with quotation marks, because the & operator in unix means to send process to background.

Comment: Yeah! This is exactly as i want. Thanks Rikudou_Sennin

Answer (score 0):

```
$your_variable = "http://www.example.com?post=123&auth=45";
shell_exec("curl '{$your_variable}'");
```

This should be working....

Comment: 1. unnecessary use of variable, 2. this answer uses curl, not lynx as the question requested.

Answer (score -1):

Regarding the original question with two parameters, the answer is in the lynx manpage:

If more than one local file or remote URL  is  listed  on  the  command
       line,  Lynx  will  open  only the last interactively.  All of the names
       (local files and remote URLs) are added to the G)oto history.

Comment: But he asked for two parameters in one URL, your answer doesn't help with that at all.